python venv uses global packages in VS-Code
I created a new env within VS-Code.
Sadly, he still uses all packages globally.
When I run which python he tells me the App data-Path.
But in the terminal he shows (venv).
I'm still a bit new to this thing, so I hope someone could help me.
Thanks a lot before.
